# Reading strings written in multiple lines from a file and storing each string in a different variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file called `one.txt`, which contains the following string, each in a different line:

```
hat
cow
Zu6
This is a sentence
```

Now, I want to store each string from each line in a different variable. For example:

```
a = 'hat'
b = 'cow'
c = 'Zu6'
d = 'This is a sentence'
```

Now, I know how to read input from files in Python. Here's what I have done so far:

```
f = open(r'<file_path>', 'r')
a = f.read()
print a
```

However, here's what `a` contains right now:

```
'hat\ncow\nZu6\nThis is a sentence'
```

How can I store each string written on each line in a different variable?

Comment: Would there only be 4 strings, and 4 variables, or is that arbitrary and can change?

Comment: The number of strings could change. It could be more or less, depending upon the test case.

Comment: My answer would create variables like a0, a1, a2, a3 , etc for each line in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the lines in an array and use the array index to access the data

```
f = open('one.txt')
text = f.readlines()
f.close()

lines = []
[lines.append(line) for line in text]

print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locals()` to get the list of local variables and create new variables using string inside it like -

```
f = open(r'<file_path>', 'r')
lcl = locals()
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    lcl['a' + str(i)] = line
print a0
print a1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the whole file content once and store it in `a` variable with `f.read()`

To read line by line, use:

`f.readline()` instead.